# Inline UL - x number of items per line; need a 1px border/separator between each line

Tags: css

I'm creating a menubar with an inline unordered list, with a 1px separator above and below. This is fine if there is only one line of lines.

Once onto 2 (or more) lines of links, I'd like to have a third separator below the first (above the second) line, but I can't for the life of me work it out.

The only thought I had was to use a background image with a line, and transparent space, which would then tile when pushed onto multiple lines, but there has to be a better way!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

All images embedded into one. 1. This is roughly how it looks now if there is only one line of links. 2. and this is what I get when it splits onto multiple lines. 3. As if you needed it.. this is what I'd like to achieve; to get that extra separator after each line of li's:

[image]

Sorry about the links.. I'm currently not allowed to embed images. All images in one; can't post more than 2 hyperlinks..

Comment: Link to images added Diodeus. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it. Using inline-block makes things a little challenging because the links need to be the same width for the LI and the UL borders to line up.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul, .menu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 0;
    list-style:none
}

.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #0000cc;
}

.menu a {
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    min-width:63px;
    font-size:16px;    
}    

.menu ul {
    width:220px;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
    border-top:1px solid #002080;
    border-bottom:1px solid #002080;
}
```

Comment: Hey Diodeus, couple of things.

I submitted an edit earlier, basically just to comment out `border-bottom:1px solid #002080;`, as it gives a double line at the bottom.

Comment: Oh, I thought that's what you needed. The pic is a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Too late to edit last comment. Should've been :

Hey Diodeus, couple of things.

I submitted an edit earlier, basically just to comment out `border-bottom:1px solid #002080;`, as it gives a double line at the bottom.

Also, the border under the 2nd (or rather, last) line of links is only as wide as the span of the links themselves. So if you change the width to anything else (fixed width, or %100), the lower border is too short. See: http://jsfiddle.net/PHeYx/

Comment: Sorry, it does look a bit fuzzy embedded. Original, at 100% is ok.

That is easily removed, the real issue is the width of the li bottom border not being the same width as the top border. See my last comment.